# Make a tag act like input button

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, get, hyperlink

How can I make an `<a href="http://test/com/tag/test">Test</a>` act like a form button? And by acting like a form button I mean that when clicking the link to do a `method="get"` or post in order to be able to capture it by get or post.

Not necessary has to be a link, I can adapt in order to make it work like that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to submit a form using a link:

HTML --

```
<form action="my-page.php" id="my-form" method="post">...</form>
<a href="#" id="form-submit">SUBMIT</a>
```

JS --

```
$(function () {
    $('#form-submit').on('click', function () {

        //fire the submit event on the form
        $('#my-form').trigger('submit');

        //stop the default behavior of the link
        return false;
    });
});
```

Docs for `trigger()`: http://api.jquery.com/trigger

If you want to submit the form without leaving the page, you can use an AJAX call:

```
$(function () {
    $('#form-submit').on('click', function () {

        //cache the form element for use later
        var $form = $('#my-form');
        $.ajax({
            url     : $form.attr('action') || '',//set the action of the AJAX request
            type    : $form.attr('method') || 'get',//set the method of the AJAX reqeuest
            data    : $form.serialize(),
            success : function (serverResponse) {

                //you can do what you want now, the form has been submitted, and you have received the serverResponse
                alert('Form Submitted!');
            }
        });
    });

    $('#my-form').on('submit', function () {

        //stop the normal submission of the form, for instance if someone presses the enter key inside a text input
        return false;
    });
});
```

Docs for `$.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`.

Comment: Frankie's solution *is* using AJAX... The `$.get()` function is the same thing as `$.ajax({type:'get'})`. I just updated my `$.ajax` code to include the form's data, that's probably pretty important :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<form ....>
    <a id="whatever" href="http://test/com/tag/test">Test</a>
</form>
```

Assuming you have any element inside your form with an ID, you use jQuery to select that ID and attach a `click` event on it. On this particular case it will also use a `get` to request data from `/whatever.php` and you should fine tune it to use both `get/post` and serialize the forms data or not according to your needs.

```
$("#whatever").click(function(){
  $.get("/whatever.php");
});
```

Comment: is it must to set the `<form...>` ?

Comment: @w0rldart, no... you can do without the form.

Comment: If you want to include data from a form in your request then you can add `$('form').serialize()` as the second argument in the `$.get()` function: http://api.jquery.com/serialize

Comment: am I putting this wrong or `$.get()` doesn't refresh the page?

Comment: I need to refresh the page because when sending the a's data to controller that gets the data it will auto build a link

Answer (score 0):

And without jQuery

```
<form id="your_form">
    <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('your_form').submit(); return false;">submit</a>
</form>
```